# C# winform application with Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I developed a small application in C# in which I use a SQL Server database, but when I run my application I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

Can anyone help me fix this error?

[The code of my save button shown in this image where exception error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GElv.jpg)   and
My app.config. file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionstring>
    <add name="dbx" connectionstring="Data Source=JAWADKHAN-PC;Initial Catalog=jawad;Integrated Security=True" Providername="System.Data.SQLClient">
    </add>
      </connectionstring>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please show us your `app.config` file! Obviously something is wrong with the **configuration system** (as the exception message clearly states)

Comment: the application is unable to load configurationsection, posting your app.config here could certainly help.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question with the relevant save code rather than a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app.config file. 
Add configSections after configuration section.
change sequence like :

```
 <configuration>
     <configSections>
      ....
     </configsections>
     .
     .
```

if this does not solve your problem then post app.config file to review.